# Update my wiki from Excel macro

Tags: python, excel, xml-rpc, confluence, vba

I'm currently able to update my [confluence](/questions/tagged/confluence) wiki page using [python](/questions/tagged/python) script like follows:

```py
import sys
from xmlrpclib import Server
s = Server("https://my.wiki.root/rpc/xmlrpc")
token = s.confluence2.login("user", "passwd")
page = s.confluence2.getPage(token, "WIKI SPACE", "page")

page["content"] = '<xml content>'
s.confluence2.storePage(token, page)
```

[[credits to Atlassian's Confluence XML-RPC and SOAP APIs](https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/deprecated-apis/confluence-xml-rpc-and-soap-apis)]

But I can't install Python (I don't know much about this great language) on my PC, and I wondered if I could do it (nearly) as easily **with Excel**. I'm trying this:

```
Sub updatePage()    
    Dim URL As String, myXML As String
    Dim xmlHttp As Variant    
    Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")

    myXML = "<my xml>"

    URL = "https://my.wiki.root/rpc/xmlrpc"
    xmlHttp.Open "POST", URL, False

    #' I specify my content type
    xmlHttp.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"

    #' Here I'm less and less sure
    xmlHttp.send "pageId=248091993&editorFormat=" + myXML

    #' This is void...
    MsgBox xmlHttp.responseText

End Sub
```

I just get nothing in `responseText`. I don't know where to look.

- How can I "emulate" these python commands (without having to install eerie softs like [pyxll](https://www.enthought.com/products/pyxll/))? If I've no [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) solution, I'll (easily?) fix something to send commands via [putty](/questions/tagged/putty) to a server where python can run... But I'm sure it can be done with Excel.
- If I knew how I could get this `s` structure returned in python with `Server("xmlrpc URL")` I would've won! But what is it? How do I get it with Excel?

Comment: In the VBA code you don't attempt to log-in - is it an option to send the login details in the URL e.g. `URL = "https://my.wiki.root/rpc/xmlrpc?id=user&pwd=passwd" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to login in your VBA code.

You do it in the Python, but why don't you in th VBA?

e.g.

```
URL = "my.wiki.root/rpc/xmlrpc?id=user&pwd=passwd";
```

This should fix your issue.